# Pull values from variables inside a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Got a "shortcode" with certain parameters and dynamic values. Need to pull these values with javascript.
This is how the shortcode looks
[offer-button width="500px" bg="#ff0000" color="#3366ff" padding="40px 50px" text="Come on in!" font="11px" weight="bold" style="italic"]

For example, I want to pull value of width ("500px" in this case).
I've decided to  pull piece of string between 'width="' and '"'. Though, I can't get rid of a feeling- there is gotta be a better way. 
Here is the code of my attempt

```
<div class="shortcode">[offer-button width="500px" bg="#ff0000" color="#3366ff" padding="40px 50px" text="Come on in!"  font="11px" weight="bold" style="italic"]</div>

var wholeshort = $(".shortcode").html();
var widthstart =  wholeshort.indexOf('width="') + 1;
var widthend = wholeshort.indexOf('"', widthstart);
var widthval = wholeshort.substring(widthstart,widthend);
```

With this, I get 'idth=', instead of '500px'

Not sure where I went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
let w = /width="(.*?)"/.exec(s)[1];
```

where `s` contains your string with data and `w` contains width value.

```js
let s= $(".shortcode").html();

let w = /width="(.*?)"/.exec(s)[1];

console.log(w);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="shortcode">[offer-button width="500px" bg="#ff0000" color="#3366ff" padding="40px 50px" text="Come on in!"  font="11px" weight="bold" style="italic"]</div>
```

Comment: Sweet! Exactly what I needed. Thanks! Can accept answer in 8 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a regular expression, and capture what comes between `width="` and the following `"` in a group:

```js
const match = $(".shortcode").html().match(/width="([^"]+)"/);
if (match) {
  console.log(match[1]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="shortcode">[offer-button width="500px" bg="#ff0000" color="#3366ff" padding="40px 50px" text="Come on in!"  font="11px" weight="bold" style="italic"]</div>
```